# Get attributes of a div dynamically generated with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to get attributes of a div dynamically generated with AJAX. Here's what I've tried:

```
$.getJSON('/json/layout', function(data) {
     $('#layout').append(data);
});
```

Here the `data` return by AJAX is something like:

```
<div id="my_div" name="my_name"></div>
```

I checked with Chrome's "Inspect Element" and seems `#my_div` was generated and appended to `#layout`. But when I print the name of `#my_div` with

```
console.log($('#my_div').attr('name'));
```

I got `undefined` in the console. I'm new to javascript, so not familiar with the basics of JS and AJAX. Could I actually get the attributes of element that is dynamically generated? If not, is there any workaround for this?

Comment: first try to print $('#my_div') only.Then we can now the value set or not

Comment: when are you printing? I hope in ajax callback

Comment: Where does the `console.log($('#my_div').attr('name'));` line appear? If it's outside the `$.getJSON()`'s success function then it's a race condition since `A`JAX is `A`synchronous, i.e. you are querying the name before the AJAX call has finished, hence name is `undefined`

Comment: @karaxuna Thanks a lot! I moved the print to ajax callback and it works. I think I will work and do all the stuff in ajax callback then.

Comment: @andyb Thanks, could I set a flag after the AJAX finish, then execute the print when flag is set? I think it sounds feasible... but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Simplest solution is to do what you want in the callback. You could set a variable but you would need a JavaScript timer to constantly check the flag's value which although possible is **not** a recommended solution. Another possibility is hijacking the [DOM Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) but this is really going over the top to solve something which should be easily achieved in the existing callback :-)

Comment: @andyb Thanks, sounds callback is more friendly to the newbies, I'll follow the easiest way :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(data).attr('name')
```

EDIT:

```
$.getJSON('/json/layout', function(data) {
    $('#layout').append(data);
    console.log($('#my_div').attr('name')); // will log result
    console.log($(data).attr('name')); // same
});

console.log($('#my_div').attr('name')); // will log undefined
```

Comment: why this ? why not  $('#my_div').attr('name') ??